# php exec does not work as expected

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec, lamp, mysql

My system: Ubuntu 11.10, LAMP Stack.

Issue:

I run the following in terminal and it does the back up correctly.

```
mysqldump -u root  dbBugTracker > BAK/dbw.sql
```

But I include it in my php code like the following and it does NOT work.

```
exec('/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root  dbTracker > BAK/dbT.sql');
```

Tips:

- I tried putting a second parameter in exec but nothing is shown except the word Array. I print it out but nothing in it.
- The file dbw.sql is actually created as a result of the exec function but it is 0 bytes.
- I tried with the full path and without for mysql and the same result is seen. i.e., 0 bytes.
- The folder **BAK** is within my project folder and I even gave it 777 permissions.
- Even tried different file names and databases but the result is the same.

I appreciate any inputs on this. Thank!

MORE INFO:
I added **2>&1** to the exec line and NOW the file contains some text but NOT the DB dump. This is an error and I have no idea how to deal with this :(
Here's the error

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
>   So this is what the output file (dbw.sql) now contains.
>   Once again, it works fine when I run the dump from terminal.

Comment: Have you tried running the PHP script from the command line - i.e. just to ensure that it is not a problem with environment variables?

Comment: did you try shell_exec function?

Comment: There you go, you are denied root user access. Like I said, you need to create a new database user in MySQL. Would you like me to append my answer with a few helpful hints? It's really simple to do. :)

Comment: @SuperNoob I tried shell_exec... Same result as my update... Return value is NULL.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Please do show me your modified answer. Really appreciate this input!

Comment: if you don't have password maybe you can try to remove the space between -u root also did you check the "sudo" command?

Comment: @SuperNoob I didn't say that I don't have a password. Rather it's stored separately in a file. This is the safest way to run the backup. So the user who may do this from the terminal won't need to know the db password. Also note that my backup works fine from the terminal. I just need to do this via php. Thus the problems :(

Comment: exec('/usr/bin/mysqldump -uroot -ppassword  dbTracker > BAK/dbT.sql');

can you try to put password, though you I already knew you have the password in the separate file.

also did you try to research on "sudo" command of unix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running that dump command as a different user while on the command line. You are running it as Apache (I assume) when using exec(). Try adding a password parameter to the exec command, or creating an php-specific user in your db with appropriate privileges.

UPDATE:: As I guessed, you are not able to use the root user while executing this dump using PHP. So, create a new user.

First, login to your database from the command line. If you are the root user, don't bother with using -u root:

```
mysql
```

Now that you're logged in, go ahead and create a new user for Apache to use:

```
GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO yourapacheuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
```

Go ahead and logout of mysql:

```
exit
```

Next, let's re-work your original code a bit...

```
$db_user = 'newusername';
$db_pass = 'pass';

$command = "mysqldump --add-drop-table -u $db_user -p$db_pass database_name > backup.file.sql";
$output = `$command`;
echo "Your database has now been backed up.";
```

Now, to execute the file, run this from the command line:

```
php path/to/sqldumpfile.php
```

Hopefully you can adapt this pseudo-code. Best of luck!

Comment: I'd love to see an answer here but it should not use a password in the command line since it will be visible to other users by simply using **history**.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. How will your users be able to track this code?

Comment: I'm no linux guru. But I have noticed that simply by going into the terminal, you can type the command "history" and there you'll find the commands that have been given. I've seen this myself.

Comment: Why on earth would your users have access to the command line on your server? :) Are you worried about other admins seeing that you backed up your database? As long as you are the only one who has access to your linux user account, or you only allow trusted individuals to access your server root, you should be just fine. The history command is totally benign.

Comment: This server is part of a simple LAN within an office. There are users who only approach it for certain operations like shutting down or start up, and sometimes troubleshooting. They shouldn't get access to the db passwords. Thus it's in a file .my.cfg.

Comment: Not to worry. If you execute this file as php from the command line (see updated answer), it will not be available from the history command at all. You can also erase the history, if you are feeling paranoid. http://www.thelinuxblog.com/linux-history-command/

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I guess I'll have to go with your method. But I really hope we find a method (at least in the future) to do this without the password in the exec line. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How do you print it?
Debug it like this:

```
<?php

exec('/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root  dbTracker > BAK/dbT.sql', $output);

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Here's the output:
array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get it working on the command line. Verify that this produces the desired results prior to using PHP's exec():

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -p YOUR_PASSWORD dbTracker > BAK/dbT.sql
```

If it DOES work, then it's an issue somewhere in your PHP config.

The first thing to check is    safe_mode. Are you using safe_mode? What version of PHP are you running?

Another possibility may be that your PHP user does not have permission to use the mysqldump binary.

Comment: Remove space between -p switch and password string for security.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, it WORKS from the terminal but not in PHP. And I DON'T use a password in the terminal, rather a separate file. So it works in the terminal.

Comment: fafe_mode is off. php ver = 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6

Comment: I think you need to pass it the -p parameter with the password like I showed in my example - just try it for kicks if nothing else.

Comment: I don't think you understand the security implications here. Having a PHP script that passes your MySQL password to exec() is no less secure than having the password in your mysql_connect() call. Specifically speaking, it DOES NOT add it to your bash history if that's what you're thinking? But even if it did, anyone with access to your bash history could presumably be able read any file you use to store your password.